# Resultant LinQ Query to compare

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

**In .NET 3.5, ASP.NET using C#**

From the below Query,

```
var query = table.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(p => p.Field<string>("Customer_Code") == "1001")
             .Select(p => new 
                           {
                              Location = p.Field<string>("Location"),
                              Country = p.Field<string>("Country")
                           })
              .Distinct();
```

I want to compare the resultant **query** results such as  Location, Country with each DataRow of a **DataTable** *Location* and  *Country*

OR In Reverse way,
I want to compare each Query result with each DataTable Row

How can i perform the same?

Sample Datatable:

```
Location     Country
Bangalore    India
Hyderabad    India
Florida       USA
London        UK
Delhi        India
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you do the following to check for a match:

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
   var result = query.SingleOrDefault(x=> 
            x.Location.ToLower() = row["Location"].ToLower() 
            && x.Country.ToLower() = row["Country"].ToLower()
        );
   if(result != null)
   {
        //Hurray, result is a match!
   }
}
```

*Note:*
*A `.Where(...).Count >0` check might be better dependant on what you will find in the query. If you expect multiple hits, use `.Where()` instead of `.SingleOrDefault()`

**New idea**
If you don't mind processing your DataTable and storing it in an IEnumerable, you could use LINQ-joins to connect the two lists. A bit harder but I think it will be more efficient.

Comment: I didn't find  .ToLower() at row["Location"]


Getting Error:

'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToLower' and no extension method 'ToLower' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: .ToString().ToLower() then :-) Also, check out my new idea. A bit trickier but it will be faster.

Comment: Pls provide sample/Example with LINQ-Joins

Comment: Getting some error with your code

 var result = query.Where(x =>
                             x.Field<string>("Location").ToLower() == row["Location"]
                             && x.Field<string>("country").ToLower() == row["Country"]
                         );

Comment: Why use x.Field<string>("Location").ToLower() instead of x.Location.ToLower()? Also, result will never be null if you use a Where. Your if-statement will have to check against result.Count() == 0. Also, what error? What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: I didn't find x.Location or x.Country. Hope you are aware that i'm oing with datatables, DataExtensions. 
Error: Error 21 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Location' and no extension method 'Location' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you build the query variable like you do in your example, you should have a Location and a Country variable you can address...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6191/discussion-between-sukumar-and-flater)

Comment: Doing `SingleOrDefault` inside the loops is rather slow. (You would have to go through the list every time). Rather add the items to a `HashSet` before the loop and use that for fast lookup. Or use a `join` (Uses a set internally)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

create a class

```
Class Temp
{
    public String Location {get;set;}
    public String Country {get;set;}
}
```

then

```
List<Temp> list = table.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(p => p.Field<string>("Customer_Code") == "1001")
             .Select(p => new Temp()
                           {
                              Location = p.Field<string>("Location"),
                              Country = p.Field<string>("Country")
                           })
             .Distinct().ToList();
```

then compare like this

```
foreach (Temp t in list)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
       //do your comparison
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error using List

Error:
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Temp>'

Comment: Are you doing `.Select(p => new Temp()`?

Answer (score 1):

How about Intersect? See http://gehirnwindung.de/post/2010/05/19/LINQ-Extension-Methods-Intersect.aspx

Comment: In the example given, you work with to Lists and this should be possible also from DataTables or similar.